# How to add specific image by id in get method in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have 2 states of any image I pass it to server

is_banner : 0 or 1

1 is banner and 0 is not

Now, I want to bring the image that has a results 1 in specific card and the other in a specific card.

Also, I want to bring specific image by id  ( I want only one image appear )

This is my html code:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let photo of gallery"   col-12>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img  src="http://{{photo.image_url}}"  (click)="showImage(photo)">
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

TS code:

```
export class GalleryPage {
    private loading:Loading;
    private loadingShown:Boolean = false;
    private subscriptions:Array<Subscription> = [];
    private gallery = new Array<Photo>();

    constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, private service:ApiClient, private loadingCtrl:LoadingController, private alertCtrl:AlertController, private photoViewer:PhotoViewer) {
        this.loadPhotos();
    }

    loadPhotos() {
        this.presentLoading('جاري التحميل');
        let subscription:Subscription = this.service.galleryList(window.localStorage.getItem('api_key')).subscribe(data => {
        this.gallery = data;

        this.dismissLoading();
        }, err=> {
            console.log('خطأ !!!');
            this.dismissLoading();
            this.presentErrorAlert("تأكد من اتصالك بالانرنت ");
        });
        this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    }
```

and this is the json data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "image_url": "example.com/storage/nbA7GrL1XcibrBZ0VH3W5BQYGqtD97BYKq34fGFi.jpeg",
        "is_banner": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-12-31 18:10:20",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-31 19:29:06"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you solve this.
This easiest is to create two arrays from your gallery array like so :

```
export class GalleryPage {
    private loading:Loading;
    private loadingShown:Boolean = false;
    private subscriptions:Array<Subscription> = [];
    public bannerGallery = new Array<Photo>();
    public standardGallery = new Array<Photo>();

    constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, private service:ApiClient, private loadingCtrl:LoadingController, private alertCtrl:AlertController, private photoViewer:PhotoViewer) {
        this.loadPhotos();
    }

    loadPhotos() {
        this.presentLoading('جاري التحميل');
        let subscription:Subscription = this.service.galleryList(window.localStorage.getItem('api_key')).subscribe(data => {
       if(data && data.length) {
          this.bannerGallery = data.filter(el => el. is_banner === 1 );
          this.standardGallery = data.filter(el => el. is_banner === 0 );
       }
        this.dismissLoading();
        }, err=> {
            console.log('خطأ !!!');
            this.dismissLoading();
            this.presentErrorAlert("تأكد من اتصالك بالانرنت ");
        });
        this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    }
```

then you can loop through those two splitted arrays separately :

```
<!-- Banner images -->
<ion-col *ngFor="let photo of bannerGallery"   col-12>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img  src="http://{{photo.image_url}}"  (click)="showImage(photo)">
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
<!-- Standard images -->
<ion-col *ngFor="let photo of standardGallery"   col-12>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img  src="http://{{photo.image_url}}"  (click)="showImage(photo)">
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

The other way to achieve this is by creating a pipe that filters your array and returns elements according to the filter so you don't need to create different arrays.

Comment: how about if i want to bring it also by id 

it will be like this ?

this.bannerGallery = data.filter(el => el. is_banner === 1 , id === 4);

Comment: Yes, but if the id is unique, then filter will return only an array containing one element provided that it exists. if you are looking to get one element by its id then its better to use find(el => el.id === 4) which will return an object unlike filter which returns an array